# Сложноподчиненное предложение с  прямой речью

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Как правильно оформлять предложения, где прямая речь внутри СПП, не делая при этом из прямой речи косвенную?
Например: Каждый, кто говорит Трава зеленая тот капитан очевидность (оставил скелет предложения, чтобы не ошибиться. "Трава зеленая" - это прямая речь).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Схема такая.

**А**: "**П**", (**и** в ССП) **а**. Теперь попробуем применить эту схему к вашему примеру (намеренно не добавляю лишних кавычек и пишу с новой строки, чтобы не запутывать со знаками цитаты).

*Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава зеленая", тот...*

Смысл предложения я не улавливаю, особенно что-то про капитана и очевидность, но начало, как мне кажется, вполне понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая", тот Капитан Очевидность.

Так как после прямой речи, которая не заканчивается вопросительным знаком, восклицательным знаком или многоточием, по структуре основного предложения требуется запятая, то ее и ставим. Если бы прямая речь не заканчивалась точкой, то после нее поставили бы тире.

Например:

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая?" - тот Капитан Очевидность.

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая?" - тот Капитан Очевидность.

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая..." - тот Капитан Очевидность.

Если после прямой речи не требуется запятая в силу структуры предложения, то ставится тоже тире после прямой речи:

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая" - и настаивает на этом, тот Капитан Очевидность.

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая!" - и настаивает на этом, тот Капитан Очевидность.

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая?" - и настаивает на этом, тот Капитан Очевидность.

Каждый, кто говорит: "Трава -- зеленая..." - и настаивает на этом, тот Капитан Очевидность.